# Maximum Transistor current and voltage

Tags: voltage, transistors, current

Assuming we have a transistor that can bear 400v 0.3A, is that means it can bear 30A if we used it for 4v only or it always withstand 0.3A?
(since P1 = P2 = 0.3 * 400 = 30 * 4)

Comment: Try asking 1 question rather than a jumble of things - btw the answer is no,no and no (not like that)

Answer (score 5):

Many power transistors have a SOA (Safe Operating Area) graph in their datasheet, here's an example:

[image]

The safe area is the bottom left side so:

Vce = 5 V at Ic = 20 Amps is just OK

but

Vce = 50 V at Ic = 2 Amps is not

Also note that it states Tc = 25 degrees Celcius meaning you have to cool this device such that its case will not exceed 25 degrees Celcius.

Also not that for a limited time, the device can handle a little higher value. It is not clear how much time it needs to recover after such an event.

Comment: -1/2 for using a 40A chart on a 0.3A part ;)

Comment: It was the clearest SOA graph I could find, and was too lazy to draw my own ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Transistors have at least three limits.

a) Voltage limit, for instance your 400v. This is governed by thickness of doped regions and doping densities. Exceeding the rated voltage will break down the junction, usually short circuiting it.

b) Current limit, for instance 300mA. This is governed by the area of the junctions, and the thickness of bond wires. Too much current will overheat the junction, or fuse the bond wires.

c) Power limit. I strongly doubt that a transistor rated for only 300mA would be able to handle as much as 120W, or that a 120W transistor would be rated for only 300mA. The power limit is governed by the thermal conductivity of the junctions to the mounting base. Exceeding the power will overheat the die.

Exceeding any one of voltage, power or current individually will destroy the transistor.

It's normal for a transistor to have a power rating much less than the product of its rated voltage and maximum current.

Answer (score 4):

- Power dissipated, Pd, in the transistor = Vce*Ic

  - and the thermal resistance Rja [0.2'C/mW] makes the junction hotter, which affects reliability
- Power increases from 0 at the origin of this graph up to the right.
- In order to exceed this Safe Operating Area (SOA) only low duty cycle pulse widths are permitted, which reduces average power.

  [image]

These are individual max limits similar to yours.

- Vceo=400v  max
- Ic = 0.3A  max
- Pd = 0.625W  max

Pd is much smaller than Vceo*Ic product due size of the part.
Ic max is often used as a switch with low drop voltage but rising with current like a resistor but faster.

**Normally one uses short pulses or only uses less than 50% of Ic max.**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't link a datasheet so I'll make this short: *No*.

For a MOSFET there are three limits you need to check:

- Maximum current
- Maximum voltage
- Maximum power

You have already identified that Voltage times Current equals Power, but keeping within the maximum *power* doesn't allow you to exceed the maximum *current* or *voltage*. All parameters must be below the limit.

It's slightly more complicated for a BJT, because its [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_operating_area) is not as simple as for a MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

No.  400 V and 300 mA are independent maximum specs.  The C-B junction will still break down beyond 400 V whether you run 3 mA thru it or the full 300 mA.  Conversely, just because you are only applying 4 V doesn't mean you get to violate the other spec of 300 mA maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Always use 70% from the max voltage or current

And select the transistor RDS on depends of your voltage . 
More higher voltage you need select the high RDS on 
Low voltage you work ( select RDS on lower )

100w max transistors  with 20 amp max and 100v max

It mean the transistor will be good to work on between 50v 2amp and 10v 10amp